# how to figure out all dependencies automatically in Node

Tags: npm

If there is one old Node project, when it installed package, it did not save that list in package.json. After node_modules folder get deleted, how can I know which modules it requires with npm or other tools?

Thanks

Comment: `npm install` and check out your `package-lock.json` file, perhaps? This only works in newer versions of Node, though.

Comment: @tadman Thanks, so you mean even the dependencies and devDependencies are empty, I still able to run npm install to let npm auto figure out what modules it needs?

Comment: It usually figures it out, but if it doesn't there's a lot of possible reasons why.